# How to initialize new entry with some data in admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = [...]
    surname = [...]
    symbol = models.CharField(unique=True)
    [...]
```

And I want to automatic generate some data in symbol field when user click "new" in admin panel. For example:

```
def generate_symbol():
    last_symbol = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('symbol')[0]
    return "%d" % (last_symbol + 1)
```

How to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Django model field's default value be defined by a function dependent on a foreign parent model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884376/can-a-django-model-fields-default-value-be-defined-by-a-function-dependent-on-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [ModelAdmin.get_form()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form), and use a [dynamic initial value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).