# Django get value from foreign key when the object was instantiated

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, instance

I am writing a simple online ordering app. I am encountering an issue when the item price gets updated. The orders that were completed also changes price. I would like to have the orders with the products have the price when the order was completed, and not get it from Product model with the latest price.

In other words, when you make a purchase for an item on Amazon, your order will have the price when you purchased the item, so it the price changes, it will still remain as the old price in your order (meaning that quantity * price will add up correctly).

```
class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ready = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '[' + str(self.order.pk) + '] ' + \
           self.product.name + ' (' + self.product.unit + '): ' + str(self.quantity)  

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Product quantities"

class Order(models.Model):
     customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
     phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
     email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")

     collection = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=ProductQuantity)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.pk)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you may want to make your question a little more clear - the code snippets etc. are great, but not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I want to have the item(s) in the order have the prices of items when the order was created, not from the latest price that the item has.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I have to simply add a price field in the ProductQuantity model and set it to the price product price with it is instantiated. I was looking for an alternative to that since I was using Product as a Foreign Key. Please let me know if there are other solutions to this. 

Is there a way to set it to the product's price when the object gets instantiated implicitly, maybe through  def create() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your models are set up quite right. Try this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    sub_total = .....
    tax = .....
    shipping = ....
    total = .....


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pk)

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product_price = models.DecimalField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    product_line_price = models.DecimalField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # If this OrderProduct doesn't have a price, it is new. 
    # So get the current Product.price and store it.
        if not self.product_price:
            self.product_price = self.product.price
        # optional
        self.product_line_price = self.product_price * self.quantity
        super(OrderProduct, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I would also put a save method on the `Order` to calculate the price and store it in the table. You could also process tax, discounts, shipping, etc. in this step.

This is the way it's typically done in eCommerce.

-- Moved back  self.product_price * self.quantity outside of if statement

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution! I was looking into editing the __init__() would a solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884376/can-a-django-model-fields-default-value-be-defined-by-a-function-dependent-on-a work too?

Comment: I'm not sure you could use `__init__()`, because I'm not sure what the state of `self.product_price` will be. We know it will be an accurate comparison by the time `save()` gets called. Save will fire when the object is written to the DB.