# Timezone in models for Django

Tags: django, django-models

I use this for a model field in rest framework, but it uploads a new timezone every time. Is there anyway to resolve it?

```
 models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=settings.DAYS),)
```

I even tried this and the error was that python 2.7 does not serialise unbound method.

```
def expire(self):
    data = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=settings.DAYS)
    return data

    models.DateTimeField(default=expire,)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it uploads a new timezone every time"?

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov it loads the datetime of the mom every time that model is called

Comment: You are using 'now' obviously it will take a diff time every time. What is the behavior you expect?

Comment: @Gocht when it is created i need the time of moment

Comment: The use `auto_now=True`. Have define `expire` method inside Model class? Try to define it outside the class

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884820/117268

Comment: @Gocht but i need it to add some days more, because it updates when it expires

Comment: I edited my comment above.

Comment: @Gocht than it gets it the first time the app is called but not when a model is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

def get_default_date():
    return timezone.now() + timedelta(days=settings.DAYS)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.DateTimeField(default=get_default_date)
```